# Linux configuration ARToolKit, make error

Tags: linux, artoolkit

I would like to compile `ARToolKit` source code on Linux, download the source code, and in accordance with the `ARToolKit` document, configuration `GLUT`, `OpenGL`, `libjpeg` other libraries.

Go to the `ARToolKit` directory and type `./Configer`
[Configer information image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmmCM.png).

Enter the `make` command,The [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqLMy.png) occurs.

What are the causes of these errors? How can I solve? thanks.

Comment: Install glib headers

Comment: I need to download `glib.h` header file or need to install any library?@MichaelO.

Comment: What Linux system do you have? If it's Debian/Ubuntu-like, you need to execute `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev` (at least this version is in my Ubuntu 14.04). If it's Redhat-like system, the package name should be smth like `glib-devel`.

Comment: After using the `sudo` command,The following message appears:`libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.`
`libglib2.0-dev set to manually installed.`@MichaelO.

Comment: My Linux system is Ubuntu14.04 version.

Comment: Try to install `libgstreamer1.0-dev`

Comment: I also found a solution for `glib.h`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108814/glib-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error-despite-installing-libglib2-0-dev

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I chose to use `gstreamer-0.10` instead of `gstreamer-1.0`, and then succeeded.@MichaelO.

Answer (score 0):

according to your configuration screenshot you miss a gstreamer installation. 
Please do:
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev

see here for more information: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=8_Advanced_Topics:build_artoolkit

Let me know if that works for you

Edit:
Just saw that there are 3 more comments and that you already installed libgstreamer to fix the issue thanks to [Michael O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489658/michael-o)

Comment: Yes,Thanks for the answer. I have solved this problem.